# Unique key warning in my Highlight function - React Native

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

I have a function that highlights my search string. It throws a warning message **"Warning: Each child should have a unique “key” prop. Check the render method of SearchItem.js".** 
For some reason it works perfectly fine in Debug mode. 
But as soon as I turn off the Remote debugging and try to search something in my TextInput it just freezes. I cannot even navigate Back.

I know we are supposed to add a unique index or id for that warning to go away. But even after assigning the id it doesn't work. 

Now I have this warning **"Encountered two children with the same key, `6b081863-7279-4e4a-999c-8e41c090a318`. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates."**

My code:

```
render(){


getHighlightedText = text => {        //highlight function
      const {value} = this.props;     // search string
      const words = value.split(/\s+/g).filter(word => word.length);
      const pattern = words.join('|');    // join it if search string is 2 words
      const tex = escape(pattern);

      const re = new RegExp(tex, 'gi')
      const children = [];
      let before, highlighted, match, pos = 0;
      const matches = text.match(re);

      if(matches != null){
      for( match of matches ){
        match = re.exec(text)

        if(pos < match.index) {
          before = text.substring(pos, match.index);

          if(before.length){
            children.push(before)
          }
        }

        highlighted = <Text style={{ backgroundColor: 'coral'}}>{match[0]}</Text> // issue is here I need to add an index
        children.push(highlighted); 
        pos = match.index + match[0].length;
      }
    }

      if(pos < text.length){
        const last = text.substring(pos); 
        children.push(last);

      }
      return <Text>{children}</Text>


    }

.
.
.
.
.
return <Text>{getHighlightedText(alert}</Text>


}
```

Now even if I add an index - the id of each item. Still it doesn't work!!!

```
const {id} = this.props;
highlighted = <Text style={{ backgroundColor: 'coral'}} key={id}>{match[0]}</Text>
```

How do I make this work?????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then You can Try this way

```
const {id} = this.props;
highlighted = <Text style={{ backgroundColor: 'coral'}} key={match.index + match[0].length}>{match[0]}</Text>
```